# Routing YII and CI

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, yii, routes, integration

I have 2 (working well) applications providing `APIs`, old one is based on **CodeIgniter 2.1** and new one on **Yes It Is framework**. I need to redirect some actions from old API to a new one. Routing should also provide filtering request methods such as `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

Folder structure looks like this:

- `ci`
- `yii`
- `router`

At first I wanted to redirect all traffic to `router/index.php` where depending on URI an appropriate app was loaded and started. It worked well with `YII`, but `CI` couldn't find it's `controllers/models/actions`.

Second idea was to use `.htaccess`, but I couldn't make `CI`, `YII` work neither. It's starting, but both of them cannot find it's `controllers/models/actions`. No errors are printed/logged into apache logs.

When those 2 apps are fired "normally" everything works properly. 
I've been changing configuration paths (to absolute ones) and still nothing. I don't want to change those applications a lot, small fixes would be much better.

Also there should be no option to fire an app without checking URI with "routes".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I stayed with PHP router as described in question post. It turn out that `CodeIgniter` couldn't find it's methods because predefined variable `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` contained a wrong path, since script was fired from another directory. I had it overridden in router file and everything seems to work properly now.